# getting error Each then() should return a value or throw in my firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting error `Each then() should return a value or throw` in my firebase function, here i have put my whole code can anyone please look into it and help me to resolve this issue ?

```
exports.test_groups_list = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    api.call('Get', { typeName: 'Group', resultsLimit: 100 })
        .then(result => {
            res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send(error)
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api call `then` returns a `promise` wrapped value so you have to first return the 
`promise` and then in next part return `response` .

```
exports.test_groups_list = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {


     let _result= api.call('Get', { typeName: 'Group', resultsLimit: 100 })
            .then(result => {
                return result
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return error
            });

      _result.then(data=>{
          res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send(data)

       })     

    });
```

Comment: This would result in the same error for the _result.then(data=>{ line

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTPS Cloud Function code does follow the rules/recommendations, as presented in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or in the official [video](https://youtu.be/7IkUgCLr5oA).

The error message comes from the fact that `eslint` detects that you have a `then()` handler that can finish without returning a value or throwing an error.

You can return `null` after sending back the response, as follows:

```
exports.test_groups_list = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    api.call('Get', { typeName: 'Group', resultsLimit: 100 })
        .then(result => {
            res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send(result)
            return null
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send(error)
            return null
        });
});
```